# Calculate $\int_{0}^1[\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x-x^2}}x $ $dy]dx$

Tags: integration, derivatives

$\int_{0}^1[\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x-x^2}}x $ $dy]dx$

I think it's an ellipse, but can't show it

Comment: Looks $y$ coordinate of the center of mass. See [this](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~conroy/m126-general/centerOfMass/centerOfMass01.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{x-x^2}} dy=\sqrt{x-x^2}$$
$$
\int dx x\int_0^{\sqrt{x-x^2}} dy=\int dx \sqrt{x-x^2}
\underbrace{=}_{x=z^2}
2\int dz z^2\sqrt{1-z^2} \\
\underbrace{=}_{z=\cos\theta} -2\int d\theta \sin(\theta)^2\cos(\theta)^2
=-2\int d\theta \cos(\theta)^2+4\int d\theta \cos(\theta)^4.
$$
Can you go on from this?

Comment: Did you do it for replacement?

Comment: @MeuluElisson what are you referring to?

Comment: It seems like the OP is asking 'did you find the integral using substitution?'

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a double integral. First integrate with respect to $y$, substitute the limits of integration in, and then do the same with $x$.